# Isolating a portion of an object within an ArrayList

Tags: java

Say I have an ArrayList containing multiple objects. Each object holds an int, a string, and a double. How would I sort through the ArrayList, retrieving all the ints from each of the objects, and adding them all together?

I’m having so much trouble figuring out how to isolate just the integer... Yea I can print the object using the .get method, but then it returns the int, string, and double.

I don’t really need code, I just need someone to steer me in the right direction in how to isolate just the int from an object in an ArrayList.

Thank you!

Comment: `.map(x -> x.getTheIntegerField())`

Comment: This is not a place for questions like "how do I approach this problem". See the Tour in the question mark menu in the upper-right. The closest valid type of question is 'I tried these approaches and still having a problem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get the Object, and then get the value from that Object using a better method.

EG - list.get(i).getMyInt().

Alternatively, this could be a nice application of Streams / Lamda’s - transform to convert from a Collection of yourObject to a Collection of Integers, and then sum these.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 or above you can use streams:

```
objectList.stream().mapToInt(object -> object.getInt()).sum()
```

It converts the list to a stream, then maps the values to ints and then it sums them up.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use typeof and then get a consistent type to do your operation